# How to convert Numpy Linear Array of pixels to Numpy multi dimensional image array

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, opencv

Hello i have a problem in which there is linear list of pixels like this:

```
[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 131 131 131 134 134 134 137 137 137 139 139 139 141 141]
```

I want to convert it into :

```
[[[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ...
  [145 145 145]
  [148 148 148]
  [149 149 149]]
```

Like normal numpy image array.

Thank for your help.

Comment: that has got to be a duplicate of a previous question. please read the introduction to numpy so you don't have to ask questions that are answered in the first chapter: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy` reshape is what you are looking for. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

However notice when you are reshaping a `numpy` array your new shape must contains same number of elements as the input array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
              131, 131, 131, 134, 134, 134, 137, 137, 137, 139, 139, 139, 141, 141])

print(a.reshape((10, 5)))
```

So in your example you cannot convert `50` element array to a `3xm` matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Use numpy.reshape() with -1, numpy will try to set first dimension by itself.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.arange(6)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> a.reshape((-1,3))
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```